# Confusion on Persistent Shopping Cart documentation

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, persistent

I was under the impression that the "Persistent Shopping Cart" does exactly that - saves the contents of the cart even for users who does not register.

I have gone through the [magento documentation](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/sales/shopping-cart-persistent-setup.html).

I am referrring the below configuration.
[image]

I have set "Persist Shopping cart" to **Yes** and added items into cart as guest users. My session expiry is set to 120 Sec, so after 120 sec my cart become empty and then after login to my account has empty cart only.

I am confused if my interpretation to the document is incorrect. My configurations is as below.

[image]

Please advice me on my doubt.

Comment: I thought the same as you. But apparently, **Persistent Shopping Cart does not work for guest visitors**. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133219 The Magento doc you are referring to is confusing, unfortunately.